# How many times have two teenagers combined for a goal in Europe's top 5 leagues?

Tags: football, trivia

In Manchester United's game against Wolves last night some interesting piece of trivia happened. The goal that won it for United was both scored and assisted by a teenager. This was only the second time in PL history that this happened.

This made me wonder how many times it has happened in Europe's other top leagues.

Comment: The source for the claim that this was the 2nd time in the Premier League is the [tweet by OptaJoe](https://twitter.com/OptaJoe/status/1753349905576308846)?
"2 - Kobbie Mainoo's (18) goal last night, assisted by Omari Forson (19), was only the second winning goal in @premierleague history to be both scored & assisted by a teenager, after Cristiano Ronaldo (19) assisting Wayne Rooney (18) for Man Utd v Liverpool (Jan '05). Carrington."

Comment: I note that the Opta tweet was specifically talking about *winning* goals that were scored and assisted by teenagers, whereas the question is asking about *all* goals.

Answer (score 1):

It happened yesterday, Saturday, February 3<sup>rd</sup> in LaLiga in the match of Deportivo Alaves against FC Barcelona: Hector Fort (2006-08-02 / 17y185d) assisted Vitor Roque (2005-02-28 / 18y6d) to score the decisive 1:3 for Barcelona in minute 63.

So, this is either an incredible coincidence that it happened twice in consecutive days, or it is not actually that rare.

It does seem that players get drafted at ever younger ages into top clubs, so I would expect this to be or at least become more common.

Some other notable facts are that both players were only substituted in during the second half, Fort in minute 46 and Roque in minute 59, only 4 minutes before he scored the goal. Roque also only played 13 minutes, collecting two yellow cards in minutes 67 and 72.